# Is there a penalty in having a non-aligned Jcc which is nearly never taken in Intel/AMD 64?

Tags: loops, branch, x86-64, memory-alignment, micro-optimization

I have a loop I use to add numbers with carry.

I'm wondering whether having `.done:` align would give me anything? After all, it will branch there only once per call to the function. I know that a C compiler is likely to align all branches *affected by a loop*. But I'm thinking that it should not cause any penalty (especially since we have rather large instruction caches now a day).

```
//    // corresponding C function declaration
//    int add(uint64_t * a, uint64_t const * b, uint64_t const * c, uint64_t size);
//
// Compile with:   gcc -c add.s -o add.o
//
// WARNING: at this point I've not worked on the input registers & registers to save
//          do not attempt to use in your C program with this very code.

    .text
    .p2align    4,,15
    .globl      add
    .type       add, @function
add:
    test        %rcx, %rcx
    je          .done
    clc
    xor         %rbp, %rbp

    .p2align    4,,10
    .p2align    3
.loop:
    mov         (%rax, %rbp, 8), %rdx
    adc         (%rbx, %rbp, 8), %rdx
    mov         %rdx, (%rdi, %rbp, 8)
    inc         %rbp
    dec         %rcx
    jrcxz       .done
    jmp         .loop

    // -- is alignment here necessary? --
.done:
    setc        %al
    movzx       %al, %rax
    ret
```

Is there clear documentation about this specific case by Intel or AMD?

---

I actually decided to simplify by removing the loop as I only have 3 sizes (128, 256, and 512) so it's easy enough to write an unrolled loop. However, I only need an add so I don't really want to use the GMP for this.

Here is the final code which should work in you C program. This one is for 512 bits, specifically. Just use three of the add_with_carry for 256 bits and just one for the 128 bits versions.

```
//    // corresponding C function declaration
//    void add512(uint64_t * dst, uint64_t const * src);
//

    .macro add_with_carry offset
        mov         \offset(%rsi), %rax
        adc         %rax, \offset(%rdi)
    .endm

    .text
    .p2align    4,,15
    .globl      add512
    .type       add512, @function
add512:
    mov         (%rsi), %rax
    add         %rax, (%rdi)

    add_with_carry 8
    add_with_carry 16
    add_with_carry 24
    add_with_carry 32
    add_with_carry 40
    add_with_carry 48
    add_with_carry 56

    ret
```

Note that I do not need the `clc` since I use `add` the first time (carry is ignored). I also made it to add to the destination (i.e. `dest[n] += src[n]` in C) because I'm not likely to need a copy in my code.

The offsets allow me to not increment the pointers and they only use one extra byte per add.

Comment: Oh lol, your size is small and fixed?  Yes, fully unrolling is very good and avoids all partial-flags problems for old CPUs.  Memory-destination `add` is efficient, but memory-destination `adc` wastes uops on Intel CPUs; usually worse than load + `adc (mem), %reg` + `mov`-store: 4 fused-domain uops on SKL for `adc %reg, (mem)` vs. 2 for `add %reg, (mem)` because Intel CPUs don't have consistent TLB across load and store within the uops for one instruction.  (See my answer on [What happens after a L2 TLB miss?](//stackoverflow.com/q/32256250) for details from an Intel architect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy clock cycles Batman, you're asking about efficiency when you used `jrcxz` over a `jmp` instead of just `jnz` after `dec`?

You'd only consider the slow `loop` or somewhat-slow `jrcxz` if you were avoiding FLAGS writes *entirely* by using `lea 1(%rcx), %rcx`.  `dec` writes all flags except CF, which used to lead to partial-flag stalls in ADC loops on CPUs before Sandybridge, but now it's fine.  A `dec/jnz` loop is ideal for ADC loops on modern CPUs.  You might want to avoid an indexed addressing mode for the `adc` and/or the store (possibly with loop unrolling) so the `adc` can micro-fuse the load, and so the store-address uop can run on port 7 on Haswell and later.  You can index the `mov` load relative to one of the other pointers which you increment with LEA.

---

**But anyway no, alignment for never-taken branch targets is irrelevant.**  So is alignment for the fall-through path of a branch that always falls through, other than usual code-alignment / decoder effects.

Alignment for *rarely* taken branch targets isn't a big deal either; the penalty is maybe an extra cycle in the front-end, or fewer instructions ready for pre-decode in a clock cycle.  **So we're talking about something like 1 clock cycle early in the front end in the case where that path actually executes.**  This is why aligning the top of a loop used to matter, especially on CPUs without loop buffers.  (And/or without uop caches and other things that hide front-end bubbles except in rare cases.).

Correct branch prediction will typically hide that 1 cycle, but usually leaving a loop results in an *incorrectly* predicted branch unless the iteration count is small and the same every time.  That first cycle might only fetch one useful instruction near the end of a fetch-block of 16 bytes (or even zero if the first instruction is split across the 16-byte boundary), with later instructions only getting loaded in the next cycle.  See https://agner.org/optimize/ for Agner Fog's microarch guide and asm optimization guide.  IDK how recently he's updated alignment guidelines in the asm optimization manual; I mostly just look at his updates to the microarch guide for new microarchitectures.

**In general uop caches and buffers between pipeline stages make code alignment a *lot* less of a big deal than it used to be**.  Aligning the tops of loops by 8 or 16 can still be a good idea, but otherwise it's often not worth putting an extra `nop` anywhere that will be executed.

You can imagine cases where it might have a bigger effect, like if previous code never executes, alignment to a cache-line or page boundary could avoid touching an otherwise-cold cache-line or page.  That can't happen with your code; there are "hot" instructions less than 64 bytes before your jump target.  But that's a different kind of effect from the usual goal of code alignment.

---

More code review:

`RBP` is a call-preserved register.  If you want to call this from C, pick a register like RA/C/DX, RSI, RDI, or R8..R11, that you aren't using for anything.  Or for Windows x64, there are even fewer call-clobbered "legacy" regs (that don't need a REX prefix).  Looks like all your loop instructions need a REX prefix for 64-bit operand-size.

`clc` is unnecessary: `xor %ebp, %ebp` to zero RBP already clears CF.  Speaking of which, 32-bit operand-size is more efficient for xor-zeroing.  It saves code-size.

You could also avoid the `dec` in your loop by indexing from the *end* of your arrays, with a negative index that counts up towards zero.  e.g. `rdi += len; rsi += len;` and so on.  `RCX = -len`.  So `inc %rcx / jnz` works as your loop condition, *and* as your index increment.

But like I said above, you might instead be better off with `lea` for a pointer increment and index your other arrays relative to that.  (`p1 -= p2`, then use `*(p1 + p2)` and `*p2`, and increment both with one `p2++` in asm.)  So you might still want a separate counter.

You can call GMP library functions instead of writing your own extended-precision loops.  They have hand-tuned asm for many different x86 microarchitectures with loop unrolling and so on.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I have [this document](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) for the ABI. It's from 2013, but I would imagine it didn't change much since. Also I changed it to be specialized to my variable sizes (128, 256, 512) removing the loop altogether. It's really clean now and will be dead fast. Call trick about the `p1 -= p2`, though! Could be useful to large loops although the memory accesses may render that not that useful.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: [Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18133812).  The basics of the calling convention (arg-passing regs, and which are call-clobbered vs. preserved) haven't changed since initial AMD64 hardware was released in ~2003, though.  The `p1 -= p2` trick of indexing one array relative to another just saves a fused-domain uop inside the loop while still allowing one array to use a non-indexed addressing mode; it's most useful for medium-sized cases.  If you knew your inputs were always large, you'd just unroll enough to hide loop overhead.